# Getting error while trying to use SignalR in Angular4 & .NetCore 2.0 application

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to use SignalR 1.0.0 alpha2 in my Angular 4 & .NET Core 2.0 application, based on [this](https://damienbod.com/2017/09/12/getting-started-with-signalr-using-asp-net-core-and-angular/) article. Here is my CommentsComponent:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { AuthService } from "angular4-social-login";
 import { SocialUser } from "angular4-social-login";
 import { AuthenticationService } from "../services/auth/auth.service";
 import { Http } from '@angular/http';
 import { UserComment } from './UserComment';
 import { HubConnection } from '@aspnet/signalr-client';
 import { User } from "../login/User";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-comments',
    templateUrl: './comments.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./comments.component.css']
})

export class CommentsComponent implements OnInit {

private loggedUserName: string = "";

private _hubConnection: HubConnection;
public async: any;

private commentTitle: string;
private commentText: string;
private commentAutor: string;

messages: string[] = [];

private Comments: Array<UserComment> = new Array<UserComment>();

constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService, 
    private httpService: Http) {
    this.checkUser();
    this.authService.getLoggedInName.subscribe(name => this.changeName(name));
}

private changeName(name: string): void {
    this.loggedUserName = name;
}

ngOnInit() {

    this._hubConnection = new HubConnection('http://localhost:4200/commentsPublisher');
    this._hubConnection.on('Send', (data: any) => {
        const received = `Received: ${data}`;
        this.messages.push(received);
    });

    this._hubConnection.start()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Hub connection started')
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error while establishing connection')
        });
}
```

But every time when i try to open connection on my client side i'm getting the error: `Error: Failed to start the connection. SyntaxError: Unexpected token G in JSON at position 0`

Of course, my `Startup.cs` file was configured, and class derived from HUB was created.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<CommentsPublisher>("commentsPublisher");
            });

            app.UseCors("AllowAny");

            //another stuff
        }
```

And my  comments publisher:

```
public class CommentsPublisher : Hub
{
    public Task PublishReport(string data)
    {
        return Clients.All.InvokeAsync("OnCommentsPublisher", data);
    }
}
```

So, any ideas ?

**UPDATE**: I'm fixed my problem with updating packages to version 4.4.6 and refusing the Identity Authentication.

Comment: Using webtools go to the Network tab and see the responses the client received. I think the server is returning an error or something to this effect but the client is expecting JSON.

Comment: The response of my request is `GET ,SET`

Comment: This is the problem - the OPTIONS request should return something like `{
  "connectionId":"807809a5-31bf-470d-9e23-afaee35d8a0d",
  "availableTransports":["WebSockets","ServerSentEvents","LongPolling"]
}`. The client tries parse the response as JSON but "GET, SET" is not a valid JSON response so the parser throws on the first character - hence `Unexpected token G in JSON at position 0`. Your server seems to be somehow misconfigured - I wonder if the response is for `Allow` header that does not allow OPTIONS. Do you run IIS/Nginx in front of your app?

Comment: I was using kestrel, but yesterday i tried to use IIS. It's the same result. 
About options and configured connections, my cors configured: 

services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAny", x => {
    x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin();
   }));

Comment: You need to figure out who sends "GET,SET"

Comment: II'm having the same issue. (not using any authentication at all). I'm not able to figure out who sends the "GET, SET" (used both IIS express and kestrel). Any ideas to what I could try?